# Data Vault 2.0: non-reference identification for LINK

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, data-vault

I wish to represent an entity that is identified both by the the identities of other entities (foreign keys), and an extra bit of information. Below is a specific scenario.

Entities:

- Products
- Customers

When a customer purchases a product, an order is made. An order also includes an ordinal number which indicates different purchases for the same set of customer and product. For example, if customer James purchases product glue 2 times, then I will have (James, glue, 1), (James, glue, 2). The identification of an order is the combination of customer, product, and ordinal number (this is by business requirement, also to facilitate subsequent data update/correction).

I then turn Products into a HUB, Customers into a HUB, and Orders into a LINK between the 2 HUBs.

*What I am trying to figure out is how I can include the ordinal number in the Order LINK.*

One suggestion I have is to make a HUB to store the ordinal number, and prefill it with ordinal numbers, (there has never been any customer who purchases the same product 100 times, so 100 lines of prefill should be good enough). Then the Order LINK can also reference the ordinal number HUB to have some identification.

Please let me know if this is a good approach (I do not really like the fact that I have to prefill something, e.g. making assumption, for the database to work). If it is not, what is a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

What you might need is a *link satellite*, which can store additional data regarding a transaction. For every transaction taken you can create satellite data.

So regarding your example, there would be one link entry for the transaction. Additionally, two satellite entries with the ordinal number will be created. This should be a *multiactive satellite*, the *LoadEndDate* will be omitted.

If done this way, you should be able to add any additional data you need for the transaction.